# OpenGL blending mode and depth buffer

Tags: android, opengl-es

The read circle is nearer to the viewer and the texture has a transparent background.

(Both objects are squares with the same size, just different texture and x, z coords).

I want:

[image]

But I have:

[image]

I know I have to do something with blending modes and maybe the depth buffer, but I don't know exactly what. Can someone help me?

The current code to load the texture:

```
public void initTexture(GL10 gl, Bitmap bitmap) {
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    int[] texture = new int[1];
    gl.glGenTextures(1, texture, 0);

    textureId = texture[0];
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

The relevant part of drawing, for each of these objects:

```
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    gl.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,  GLES10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);
```

Thanks!

Note: I'm using OpenGL ES 1.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want blending, because that would mix the colors. What you want is *alphatesting*. Use `glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)` and `glAlphaFunc` to set it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your blend function :

try :

```
 gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_DST_ALPHA);
```

Comment: Didn't change anything, besides the color of both objects is now brighter (like pastel).

Comment: oh yes sry, I was thinking about 'glAlphaFunc' did you try the solution from Bartek ? it seem relevant.

Comment: Yes, but it's not complete and my first tries didn't improve anything... will try more when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable writing to depth buffer:

```
glDepthMask(false);
```

Then draw blue quad first, and then the red one (which is closer to camera) over it. After drawing transparent geometry you may want to enable writing to depth buffer again with `glDepthMask(true)`.

Otherwise blue quad gets culled by the red one.

Comment: Hm... I have a somewhat complex scene, but I'm just drawing all the quads from left to right... do I have to care about draw order? Sorry if the question is stupid, but there's already z coord in OpenGL, why I have to organize draw order? I just want that the transparent bitmaps lets show whatever is behind through...